Sorcerous Burst and Critical Hits
What happens when I score a critical hit with Sorcerous Burst? In particular, how does it interact with the extra damage a Sorcerous Burst can do?
From the description of Sorcerous Burst:

If you roll an 8 on a d8 for this spell, you can roll another d8, and add it to the damage. When you cast this spell, the maximum number of these d8s you can add to the spell’s damage equals your spellcasting ability modifier.

From the rules for Critical Hit:

Roll all of the attack’s damage dice twice and add them together.

When formulating an answer, please consider the following:

When rolling the critical damage, do 8's allow the sorcerer to roll more dice?
Does the "maximum number of these d8's you can add" apply to both the normal damage and the critical damage?

I'm leaning towards saying "first roll the normal damage subject to the rules of the spell, then roll the same number of dice for critical damage. Nothing special happens if you roll an 8 on the critical damage dice."

On the first question, the spell says:

If you roll an 8 on a d8 for this spell, you can roll another d8

Extra dice from critical hits are also part of the spell damage dice, so it's also a valid source of the explosive d8, just like the extra damage from casting it at a higher level.
On the second question, the spell says (emphasis mine):

the maximum number of these d8s you can add

So it's only limiting the explosive d8 described in the sentence before, not limiting other sources of extra d8 such as from critical hit. So a critical hit gives you more chance to maximize the explosive dice.

So if I understand correctly, after you hit, you roll 2d8 for damage (normally 1d8, but you get to roll twice with the critical hit). For each 8, you roll another 2d8 (because it's still a critical hit), subject to a maximum of your spell modifier in additional 2d8's? So a 1st level sorcerer with +3 CHA bonus that got absurdly lucky and only rolled 8's would do 8d8 damage?

@user76491 well they've got 24 + 5d8 damage, because we know 3 of those d8s resulted in 8.

I’d rule slightly differently, but I think the rules as written are ambiguous enough to allow either interpretation.
From Chapter 1 of the 2024 Player’s Handbook and Free Rules, under “Damage and Healing”, the full text of the Critical Hit rules says (emphasis mine):

When you score a Critical Hit, you deal extra damage. Roll the attack’s damage dice twice, add them together, and add any relevant modifiers as normal. For example, if you score a Critical Hit with a Dagger, roll 2d4 for the damage rather than 1d4, and add your relevant ability modifier. If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the Rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you also roll those dice twice.

The extra dice rolled for Sorcerous Burst would qualify as “other damage dice”, and it seems clear that for a critical hit you roll those same dice twice and add the results together - you don’t add extra dice. And that’s the only effect of a critical hit, so it doesn’t affect the maximum number of extra dice that can be added by rolling eights for Sorcerous Burst damage. You can’t get more than your spellcasting ability modifier.
It is still a bit ambiguous, though, since each dice now has two chances to roll an 8 and Sorcerous Burst doesn’t address that possibility. But the spell will only roll a base of 1d8 to 4d8 damage, depending on the caster’s level. The ability modifier cap on extra dice will nearly always be higher than that, so it feels like the RAI is that you should get as many bonus dice as possible on lucky rolls (up to the maximum).
So, since they know it’s a critical hit before rolling damage, I’d rule that a player can roll each of the standard damage dice twice, adding one extra dice for each 8 rolled even on the same dice. The extra dice are rolled twice too, but the cap on the number of extra dice that can be added this way stays the same.
I don’t think this is likely to break anything. Critical hits happen fairly often (5% of the time). My probability math is pretty rusty, but a level one Sorcerer with a Charisma bonus of +3 has about a 0.2% chance to roll the maximum Sorcerous Burst damage of 24 + 1d8 (since they’ll need to roll three 8s in a row to make it happen). A critical will increase their chances of getting the maximum bonus dice to about 3%, but they do have to roll the critical first; so to get 24 + 5d8 is about a 0.15% chance altogether. (Again my math’s a bit rusty, but I think I’m in the right ballpark.)
Either of those is a pretty great result for a cantrip, especially at low levels, but it just won’t happen all that often.

In this interpretation, a critical hit increases the average damage and the chance to add more dice, but doesn't increase the maximum damage? That doesn't seem RAI for critical hits. As you said, the chance of achieving it is slim... so maybe there should be a chance for the level 1 sorcerer with a +3 spellcasting modifier to do 8d8 with this spell?

@user76491 I’m not sure what you mean - in my example, it increases the maximum damage from 24 + 1d8 (4d8 with at least three 8s) to 24 + 5d8 (4d8 rolled twice, with at least three 8s rolled).
